# Cannot solve dynamic reference to constructor

Tags: java, proguard, obfuscation

I have been trying to fix this problem for a week now. I create a shadowJar (uber jar) and it starts fine. When I run obfuscation, I get an error on startup:

*Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't obtain peer field ID for class com.sun.jna.Pointer*

I have been using Proguard to run obfuscation and I always get this after the process 
"*Note: com.sun.jna.Structure accesses a constructor '(com.sun.jna.Pointer)' dynamically*"

Here is a snippet of my .pro file:

```
-dontshrink
-dontoptimize
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,LocalVariable*Table,*Annotation*,Synthetic,EnclosingMethod

-keep class com.sun.jna.** {
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
}

-keep,allowshrinking class com.sun.jna.** {
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
}
```

Am I doing it wrong or missing something important? I am assuming the message after processing is related to the start-up error I have from the obfuscated jar.

Comment: It looks like you try to obfuscate `rt.jar`

Comment: @talex I added rt.jar to the library inputs to get rid of a lot of warnings originally. Do I just not add it or is there a way to not obfuscate it?

Comment: Don't add it. It will create tons of problem later.

Comment: @talex so I removed `-libraryjars 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_191\lib\rt.jar'` from my .pro file but now I get lots of warnings and my jar isn't even created

Comment: You may create question about it. Add example of warnings (search for errors too).